# Image will show in Firefox, but not in chrome

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I'm having a problem where tags are being misinterpreted in chrome but not in Firefox. I have a cgi script which generates an image and a link to the image.

CGI script

```
if (-e $FILENAME)
{
print qq#<a href="http://blah.com/downloadfile.cgi?ID=$FILENAME"><b>Image:</b></a> #;
print qq#<img src="http://blah.com/viewimage.cgi?ID=$FILENAME"> </img>#;                      
}
```

Firefox Interpretation

`<a href="http://blah.com/downloadfile.cgi?ID=/temp_webfiles/af08e6f3291a912cf8031984acc7942a.jpg"><b>Image:</b></a> <img src="http://blah.com/viewimage.cgi?ID=/temp_webfiles/af08e6f3291a912cf8031984acc7942a.jpg">`

Chrome Interpretation

`<a href="http://blah.com/downloadfile.cgi?ID=/temp_webfiles/5eb1834ce2ea527df6c341a915b5a6fb.jpg"><b>Image:</b><img src="http://blah.com/viewimage.cgi?ID=/temp_webfiles/5eb1834ce2ea527df6c341a915b5a6fb.jpg"></a>`

Just a note, the image names will be different for the chrome and Firefox, there just randomly created.

As you can see, for both the ending image tag  don't show up and for chrome the  tag is misinterpreted.

Is there any reasons why this happens? any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: To summarize: validate your HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Close your `<img>` tags properly with **`/>`**:

```
<img src=... />
```

Comment: This is one problem with the code, but also note that the code is missing a closing quote. See my answer for the spelled-out example.

Comment: @Ben Lee: Yeah, I didn't notice it at first, never mind. Thanks for pointing out that the OP didn't even copy-paste the output correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a closing quote on your img src, and you are not closing your image tag correctly. This line:

```
print qq#<img src="http://blah.com/viewimage.cgi?ID=$FILENAME</img>#
```

Should be:

```
print qq#<img src="http://blah.com/viewimage.cgi?ID=$FILENAME" />#
```

Comment: ...or `print qq#<img src="http://blah.com/viewimage.cgi?ID=$FILENAME">#` if it's HTML instead of XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your image tag in the perl code.  You've got 
    `<img src="http://blah.com/viewimage.cgi?ID=$FILENAME</img>;`
You don't need a closing tag (instead a self closing tag), just do
`<img src="http://blah.com/viewimagine.cgi?ID=$FILENAME" />`